# Prolog replace every second item in list

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to learn Prolog, I'm having trouble defining the predicate:

In Prolog define a predicate substitute (L1, X, L2) which every second element of the list L1 (starting from the second element) replaces with element X.

Examples:

`L1 = [a, b, c], X = 1, L2 = [a, 1, c]`

`L1 = [a, b, c, d], X = a, L2 = [a, a, c, a]`

I tried this way:

```
replace( [], _, [] ) :- ! .
replace( [X|Xs], T, [Z1,Z2|Zs] ):-
  Z1 = X ,
  Z2 = T ,
  replace(Xs,T,Zs).
```

But it adds items to the second list, not replaces them.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You have to take 2 items from the first list too. The second item may be ignored (use the anonymous variable `_`). Also you may need to add another base case for when the number of items in `L1` is odd.

Comment: You can also use the same variable where appropriate. So instead of unifying `Z1` with `X` just use the same variable `X` in both places. Likewise with `T` and `Z2`.

Comment: And you may get rid of the cut `!` as it is not needed in your procedure

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are pulling items off the list 1 at a time. To replace every other item, you can do it a couple of ways:

- **Pull items off 2 at a time**

  Try this to replace the even number list elements (where the 1st element in the list is item number 1.

  You have the special case of the empty list:

  ```
  replace( [] , _ , [] ) .
  ```

  And the special case of a list of length 1:

  ```
  replace( [X] , _ , [X] ) .
  ```

  And then the general case (lists of length > 1):

  ```
  replace( [X,_|Xs] , R , [X,R|Ys] ) :- replace(Xs, R, Ys).
  ```

  Putting it all together, we get:

  ```
  replace( []       , _ , []       ) .
  replace( [X]      , _ , [X]      ) .
  replace( [X,_|Xs] , R , [X,R|Ys] ) :- replace(Xs, R, Ys).
  ```
- **Track State As You Go**

  This isn't much more difficult. And it opens the possibility of
  making things more general. To do this we use a *helper
  predicate*. Ultimately, it's not a lot different.

  First, our `replace/3` is just a wrapper around invoking the
  helper predicate, to which we pass two additional bits of state:

  - the current index value (`1`), and
  - the modulus we'll use to determine which elements get replaced

  ```
  replace( Xs, R, Ys ) :- replace(Xs, R, 1, 2, Ys).
  ```

  Here's the helper predicated `replace/5`:

  ```
  replace( []     , _ , _ , _ , []     ) .
  replace( [X|Xs] , R , N , M , [Y|Ys] ) :-
    try_swap(X,R,N,M,Y),
    N1 is N+1,
    replace(Xs, R, N1, M, Ys ).

  try_swap( _ , R , N , M , R ) :- 0 is N mod M, !.
  try_swap( X , _ , _ , _ , X ) .
  ```

  And putting it all together:

  ```
  replace( Xs, R, Ys ) :- replace(Xs, R, 1, 2, Ys).

  replace( []     , _ , _ , _ , []     ) .
  replace( [X|Xs] , R , N , M , [Y|Ys] ) :-
    try_swap(X,R,N,M,Y),
    N1 is N+1,
    replace(Xs, R, N1, M, Ys ).

  try_swap( _ , R , N , M , R ) :- 0 is N mod M, !.
  try_swap( X , _ , _ , _ , X ) .
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can write it as two functions that call themselves recursively in turn.

One replacing elements at odd positions, the other replacing elements at even positions:

```
replace_even([], _, [] ).
replace_even([H|T], R, [H|O]) :-
    replace_odd(T, R, O).

replace_odd([], _, []).
replace_odd([_|T], R, [R|O]) :-
    replace_even(T, R, O).
```